# Upgrade Dell Inspiron 15-7577

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, memory, ssd

I have Dell Inspiron 15-7577 JB9B142.
I have HDD 1TB and 8GB DDR4. 
I want to upgrade my laptop add SSD disk and +8GB DDR. I don't want to exchange the old HDD with an SSD, just add one more SSD to my laptop.
No information in web about it. I don't know what SSD and RAM will fit.

I want to buy a SoDIMM DDR4 8GB 2400 MHz HyperX Impact Kingston (HX424S14IB2/8) and SSD M.2 2280 250GB Samsung (MZ-N6E250BW).

Do these parts fit my laptop or do I need buy an NVMe instead SATA3?

Comment: Information about maximum RAM supported, type and configuration as well as other supported upgrades should be in the user's manual and/or the manufacturer's website.

Comment: No information. +8GB is ok to my laptop but the main question is SSD

Comment: I haven't found an official Dell page that explicitly shows the length of the NVMe slot, but if you have a clean workspace and ground yourself, you can turn off the laptop, open it up, and have a look.  You can see some example sizes a couple pages down here : https://www.pcmag.com/roundup/361090/the-best-pci-express-nvme-solid-state-drives-ssds

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this page has your laptop's specs : https://www.dell.com/mk/business/p/inspiron-15-7577-laptop/pd .

DDR4 2400MHz is the original RAM speed, so the RAM listed in the original question will probably work.

The spec page I found doesn't explicitly say that it has an NVMe slot.  However, it does say "PCIe SSD" option, NVMe drives became available in 2014, and the laptop is from 2015.  Other Google searches appear to confirm that it's got an open NVMe slot, but I'm not certain of the length.  Ensure that you have a little screw of the proper size to perform the install, because Dell probably didn't leave one rattling around inside.

You might have to download specific drivers for that new NVMe SSD.  This is relatively easy when you already have a working OS on the SATA HDD.  Windows 10 might even do it automatically.

If you feel comfortable changing your boot drive to the NVMe SSD, the laptop will perform much faster on almost everything.  If you haven't installed an OS before, it's a big project.  You have to back up everything important first.  Since there's no optical drive, you would have to create an install USB.  You might have to deal with BIOS RAID / cache / AHCI mode.  You might have to deal with storage drivers during the OS install.  You might have to set the NVMe drive as the boot drive in the BIOS.  Finally, if you don't back up as needed, you might lose all of your documents (just saying again).

Comment: Thanks! I think RAM that i want to buy is fit my laptop. But the main problem is SSD. SSD M.2 2280 250GB Samsung (MZ-N6E250BW) this what I order ant its not a NVMe this is SATA m2. ANd idk It will fit/work in my laptop or not. The main question. Thanks

Comment: I apologize for making this a conversation (SuperUser is not well designed for conversations, but just simple question/answer format).  Since the page that I have referenced states that it's a PCIe SSD, not SSD, I don't believe that the SSD model you posted will work.  If you mean "RAID" instead of RAD, then it's not a good choice for matching with a traditional SATA device, because the RAID will perform at the slower SATA speed.

Comment: It is worth your time to contact Dell Support directly to confirm if this laptop has SATA or NVMe m.2 slot .  Some computers have slots that can do either.  I haven't found a Dell page that says explicitly, so it's better to ask the manufacturer directly.